# Why are brass nuts supposed to be good for sustain on guitars?

Tags: electric-guitar

For the 2000th question on guitars - brass nuts are well thought of to enhance sustain on guitars, but surely that will only be the case with the open strings. Is there a secret that we need to know about?

Comment: The cynic in me wants it to be about as fundamentally sound as tying knots in your hifi cables... but I'm open to persuasion ;) I always thought the best way to improve sustain was turn your amp up more & stand facing it ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin - I thought tying knots produced a slight delay - oh no, to get that you need a really really *long* cable...

Answer (score 3):

They are denser than bone, plastic, or other materials (copper is the second most dense common metal after lead). That increased mass leads to increased inertia at the top of the neck which increases the mechanical impedance at the nut which means energy is more slowly transferred from the string to the neck. Energy staying in the string longer means longer sustain.

In addition, the stiffness of brass is about three times the stiffness of Micarta (a common high-quality plastic nut material - e.g. Martin uses this on their high end guitars), and higher stiffness also leads to higher mechanical impedance. The influences of mass and stiffness on impedance are roughly equal.

I suspect the wood and thickness of the neck have much bigger effect than replacing something as small as a nut. This is because the mass and stiffness of the entire system are what is important. So increasing the stiffness or mass of one component does not necessarily increase the mass or stiffness of the whole system to a significant degree. Also, reducing transfer of energy to the neck means the vibrations of the neck are reduced so I would expect a minor tonal change.

Combined with the difficulty of cutting brass makes me think is a lot of trouble for not enough benefit. I'd go for a Fat Finger or other headstock mass device long before I'd go for a brass nut for sustain.

Comment: Good answer, but once a string is fretted, any energy in it won't reach the nut, thus the reason for the question.

Comment: @Tim Still increases the mass of the neck. Like an invisible fat finger that weighs a lot less. Are you looking for an answer for how brass nuts *supposedly* increase sustain (which is what I typed up) or actual proof and explanation that they **do** increase sustain?

Comment: I understand what you say. If that's the case, though, why haven't manufacturers built, say, more metal (=more mass/weight) into necks. I believe it's only open strings that are really affected for the better, but there's a certain hype for brass nuts. (Might be something to do with Winter !!) Changing the balance of guitars? weaker necks? (Doubt it). I'm interested in any and all reasons/theories. Dare I say it - Musical practice *and theory*...

Comment: @Tim Sounds like a separate question but the answers can be summarized as tone and ergonomics. Many players find guitars made from larger amounts of denser woods to be uncomfortable, so adding mass for sustain is not a tradeoff everyone wants. And while it's debatable whether a brass nut noticeably affects sustain, it definitely affects tone, and not in a good way for most guitarists. Finally, why re-engineer for *more* sustain? I personally want *less* sustain in many situations. Some players have put foam blocks under their strings at the bridge to kill the sound more quickly.

Comment: From a good selection of stock strats I've owned through the years, the one with the best sustain was the lightest by far - an original '64. The rest go from JP Squier '85 to [bunch o' crap] all heavier, therefore more dense & all 'sing' far less than the original. By extrapolation of the answer, lead would make a better nut than brass... but I bet it doesn't. It's resonance not density that is the key. I'd guess 'hardness' to be a greater factor than simple mass.

Comment: @Tetsujin Mass does effect the mechanical impedance, but it's not the only effect, and losses due to transfer to the body/neck are not the only losses of string energy. Cheaper guitars may have poorly cut nut slots and issues with the saddles that can lead to dramatic energy losses. You can't just compare overall mass and arrive at a conclusion about mass and sustain. **All other things being equal**, higher mass will lead to higher sustain. Yes elasticity is also a factor. I would expect resonance to generally reduce sustain for electric guitars. Unless you mean feedback.

Comment: @Tetsujin Lead is the most dense common metal ahead of copper. A lead alloy would be better than just raw lead for many reasons, but the issue of toxicity and by extension regulations on uses of lead in all kinds of products prevent lead alloys from being used in many products. AFAIK, the popularity of brass is about tone. I don't see a lot of marketing of brass nuts for sustain.

Comment: All I know is my old Strat, with bone or plastic nut & which weighed less than half any other guitar I've ever played, had better sustain [& incidentally was louder] unplugged than almost any other electric I've ever tried. idk really *why*, it just did.

Comment: @Tetsujin I would guess the woods used were stiffer and the workmanship was finer leading to much lower losses due to friction and other parasitic effects. But I am editing in stiffness as another factor in mechanical impedance. Thanks!

Comment: I haven't heard about fatfingers. They look promising, but do they really improve sustain? They supposedly cause the headstock to resonate less, but then again more energy is absorbed to make the larger mass resonate. Perhaps less high frequencies are absorbed. I'm sceptical, but perhaps I'll try something DIY.

Comment: @YeDawg - if the headstock vibrating *less* gives *more* sustain, then maybe that's where the brass nut gains something. But again, only with open strings.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - lead never did get used for parts of instruments even before it harmed our health, but copper and brass abound - whole instruments are made from it ! Lead doesn't seem to 'ring' as well as brass or copper, somehow. Maybe too soft?

Comment: @Tim I believe the decreased vibrations from adding mass onto the headstock would be due to the increased energy required to vibrate it. If that's true, the energy loss stays the same. However i have seen some luthiers insert strips of maple or carbon fiber to make the headstock stiffer, which could lower the energy loss and potentially increase sustain. Of course a brass nut might have less friction as well, which might effect the sustain.

Comment: @Tim Engelmann spruce and lead have very similar elastic moduli and hardnesses. The tensile strength of Engelmann spruce is about four times that of lead. But the density of lead is about 200 times that of the spruce. That gives spruce a very advantageous stiffness to weight ratio, which is a good thing for musical instrument materials to have if you want them to vibrate in good ways.

Comment: I suspect that sustain i less important if the string is fretted, since those notes are more likely to be passing tones (assuming 1st position). Sustain on the final note/chord is more likely to be heard (because you have stopped playing) and I bet more often than not there will be open strings ringing away.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it has anything to do with sustain (to be fair, **there are no replacement parts that miraculously improve sustain**). The idea is supposed to be that by having a nut material similar to the fret material (ie. metal), you get **more tonal consistency between fretted and open notes**. Compare a string anchored on nickel and steel to one anchored on brass and steel. I guess you would get the same consistency by making the frets out of bone...

Oh and for sustain, use a stiff pick, hit the strings hard, use lots of compression and distortion, high volume, and stand close to the speakers.

Comment: Some electric guitars appear to have  inherently good sustain, even when not plugged in, but, yes, those are all contributory factors.

Comment: You can get good sustain on an electric by turning up the volume and playing quietly. This works with light strings, thin pick, and no distortion or compression.

Comment: @DavidBowling Also: a neat trick to get around triple the perceived sustain is to strike a note or a chord with the volume turned down, then raising it as it starts decaying.